# Facebook php sdk photo upload success but page album does not show image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload to an page album photos using Facebook PHP SDK. Everything seems to work as there is no error response. But I cant see the picture inside page album? Can you help me to clarify how to upload to an album?
my config file :

```
  return array(
        'appId' => 'foo',
        'secret' => 'bar',
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'allowSignedRequest' => true // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
    );
```

and my code while i try to send a file :

```
            $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
            #The id of the fanpage
            $fanpage = '1404264166489378';
            #The id of the album


            $message = 'Fotoğraf başarı ile yüklendi';
            $album_id = "1404677233114738";

            $facebook->api($album_id.'/photos','POST',[

                'photo' => new CURLFile($path.$fileName,'image/jpeg'),
                'message' => $message
                ]);
```

Comment: you just shared your appID/secret with the whole world... I've removed them, but you should consider changing them.

Comment: no problem ..this is a test app. but I will change it thank youç

Comment: Is your app out of sandbox mode yet?

Comment: yes it is in sandbox mode

Comment: @ytsejam did you find any solution? I am also facing the exact same issue.

Comment: This was an old question. here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album/photos .. you need publish_actions permissions.  I need long auth tokens are necessary .. any more questions ? I will try to help

Comment: what is "long auth tokens"? I've already added publish_actions permissions and the image uploads with success but just unable to see that in album. For more details please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022214/image-uploaded-to-facebook-but-not-shown-on-page

Comment: Does facebook app needs to be live to see content uploaded through it?