# Image uploaded to Facebook but not shown on page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image to a specific album on Facebook page through Graph api call from ipad app. Everything is working correctly and the response from Facebook returns success with the id of post but I just can't see the image uploaded on the page. I am doing this using Appcelerator Titanium. Following is my code:

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = 'MY APP ID';
fb.permissions = ['read_stream'];

function postImageToFb(){
    fb.reauthorize(['publish_actions','manage_pages'], 'me', function(e){
      if (e.success) {
        // If successful, proceed with a publish call
        var data = {
            source: Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory+'/image.png').read(),
            message: 'Hello pic'
        }
        fb.requestWithGraphPath('<album-id>/photos',data,'POST',function(e){
            alert('Post to fb: '+JSON.stringify(e));
            if(e.success){
                alert('Photo submitted successfully to fb.')
            }else{
                alert('Failed to upload photo to fb: ')
            }
        })
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unknown result");
        }
    }
  });
}

$.btn_submit.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(fb.loggedIn){
    postImageToFb();
  }else{
    fb.authorize();
    fb.addEventListener('login',function(e){
        if(e.success){
            postImageToFb();
        }else{
            alert('Failed to login fb: ',e);
        }
    })
  }
})
```

I have used the same account for creating Facebook app, page and Facebook login from app so it shouldn't be the problem. What might be the problem? Can someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Does facebook app needs to be live to see content uploaded through it?

Comment: you need an access token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could never get the requestWithGraphPath() to work with a page, even with the access token FOR the page. It would always post to the Pages wall, but as my personal profile.

See how I ended up doing it here (underneath the profile explanation is an explanation on Pages): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144909/4121164

Comment: Fighting with appcelerator trying to get this to work ;) Glad you got it going!